# Python: Twitter api results come out blank

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to collect 180 tweets from, say, Donald Trump. My code:

```
 import argparse
 from urllib.parse import urlparse 
 import urllib
 import csv
 import tweepy
 import codecs

 !python ./twitter_search.py -c 180

 import os
 os.system("python twitter_search.py Donald Trump -c 180")

 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import statsmodels.api as sm

 df = pd.read_csv("result_Donald_Trump.csv", index_col=0)

 df.head(5)
```

Putting Donald Trump in  df = pd.read_csv("result_Donald_Trump.csv", index_col=0) gave me a FileNotFoundError, I think because of the space so I put an underscore. When I did the file was created, but was blank.

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mY4p.png)

Why does it give me blank results?